# uv unwrapping difficulties with a table leg

Tags: uv-image-editor

i have tried various unwrapping methods to no avail. this is quite an unusual shape so i understand blender has a hard time trying to follow the topology. i have added seams to the top and bottom of the legs as well as the side but when unwrapped one part seems significantly stretched. smart uv project makes the texture look patchy also. what is the best way of unwrapping this with the least distortion possible?

[image]

Comment: Its hard to describe ... could U please share a .blend file so I could make changes and send it back to You? _(btw which leg is selected now? There are three on the image but none has selected vertices like in your UV editor and something looks really weird tbh imo. U have more separated meshes in one object? Better to UV one leg and then make copies of it btw.)_

Comment: yes, a .blend would be helpful. That mesh is difficult to unwrap particularly if you want a straight, seamless grain. Try creating many 'bands' around the feet to separate the different heights. The main part of the leg will have to be manipulated in the 2D editor. Try watching [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VgLlurusWc)

Answer (score 1):

I think Mark Seam and Unwrap works pretty good, perhaps share your file + texture of this single object so that we can test

[image]